# How to convert String list into List Object in java..?

Tags: java, string, list

I have a String as follows :

```
s = "['a','b','c']"
```

How can i convert this string into List Object..??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like

```
s = s.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
String[] split = s.split(",");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(split);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove brackets
2. `String.split()` using `,` separator
3. For each item remove quotes (`'`)
4. No 4th point

Comment: And for bracket removal - String.substring(startIndex, endIndex)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split()` method on `s`. So, `s.split(",");` will produce an String array of the following form: `["['a']", "'b'", "'c']"]`. I'll leave it to you to read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to figure out how to get exactly what you want in the array.

Once have the array, you can add all the elements to a List using the following:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(split);
```

EDIT: wrote wrong method.